# NoReverseMatch at

Tags: django

Помогите правильно написать url паттерн, сейчас выглядит так:

```
url(r'^diagnose/parent/(?P<code>\w+)/', views.show_parent, name='show-parent'),
```

падает с таким сообщением:

```
Reverse for 'show-parent' with arguments '(u'F00-F99',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'back/diagnoses/diagnose/parent/(?P<code>\\w+)/']
```

Что нужно, чтобы этот аргумент корректно обрабатывался?

Comment: Покажите ваш reverse

Comment: <td><a href="{% url 'back:diagnoses:show-parent' diagnose.parent_code %}">{{ diagnose.parent_code }}</a> </td>

Comment: Вот так: `code=diagnose.parent_code`

Comment: Reverse for 'show-parent' with keyword arguments '{u'code': u'F00-F99'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'back/diagnoses/diagnose/parent/(?P<code>\\w+)/']

Comment: А если тогда не выпендриваться с `\w` и просто написать `(?P<code>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)`

Comment: Супер, спасибо! Помогло!